# Calculating Radius of Arc over a Rectangle

Tags: geometry, education, mathematical-physics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rB7A2.jpg)

I want to make a PCB for street light and I am facing difficulties in calculating the Arc over the top of the casting.

The Dimensions are :
L = 180 mm ( Length of the rectangle )
B = 90 mm
L from Top of the ARC = 195 mm.

How do I calculate the Arc radius that joins the rectangle.

I have included the image for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, the figure shows the solution.

[image]

If $x$ is the radius $\overline{AF}$ than 
$$
\overline{AG}^2+(x-\overline{EG})^2=x^2
$$

so, in your case, $x$ is the  solution of the equation
$$
45^2+(x-15)^2=x^2
$$

Comment: Thank you sir I also have another question regarding point on a circle. How to calculate a point anywhere on a circle. I know the radius.

Comment: The rules of this site provide that no new, different, questions are asked in the comments , but you can make a new question. And if you like an answer it's a good practice to accept it.

Comment: Okay, I shall do that.